# Facebook Graph API on android doesn't return Email sometimes

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using following code to retrieve more info about a user after login and i am using Graph API, but the thing is this code sometimes returns a valid email sometimes not, for the same user, in other case its not returning for another user at all. Not returning an email can be understood as it might be due to user not having a valid email, but same user it works sometimes and sometimes not.

```
 fbLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                    try {
                        if (json != null) {
                            String email = "";
                            if (json.isNull("email") == false) {
                                email = json.getString("email");
                            }
                            Log.d("email", email);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of research and some code, found that along with above code it was needed to set permission with Facebook LoginButton object as follows, hope it helps someone. Also not that above code returns email only if the email is verified, but if an account with unverified email, above code won't return email.
Add following code in that case

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
```

Comment: What if you don't use the LoginButton control?

Comment: LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));